# Can someone tell what's wrong with this c program?

Tags: c

it prints all the strong numbers(numbers which are equal to the sum of     factorial of the digits.) till m.

I ran this in code block.

It is taking the input, but after that, it says that the `filename.exe` has stopped running. What could be the reason? Could something be wrong with the compiler?

All other codes are running well.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int);
int main()
{
    int j,n,m,sum=0;
    scanf ("%d",m);
    for (j=1; j<=m; j++)
    {
        n=j;
        while (n>0)
        {
            sum= sum + fact(n%10);
            n=n/10;
        }
        if (j==sum)
            printf("%d  ",j);
    }
    return 0;

}


int fact (int n)
{
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return fact(n-1)*n;`
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%d",m);` --> `scanf ("%d",&m);`

Comment: Lean how to use a debugger. Really. It's worth the time spent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enabled compiler warnings, you'd get something like:

```
main.c:7:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf ("%d",m);
            ~~  ^
```

which makes it very clear what the problem is. `scanf` needs a pointer to an int to be able to read into it: `scanf("%d", &m);`

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. my compiler didn't show any error.

Comment: Better turn them on then. (warnings != errors)

Comment: turned on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) wants address of destination variable using %d format specifier.

```
scanf ("%d",m);
```

must be

```
scanf ("%d", &m);
```

Side note: **take care of `int` range**:    `–2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.